# Clear way to use canvas html5 with React without render all canvas shapes all time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, etl, saas

Currently, i work on ETL project with Saas platform using React stack.
i try to find the clean way to use canvas with React
and render juste some shapes of Canvas when the React Render function is called
without create a new canvas each time

My idea is to have a component react with JSX like this:

```xml
    <MyReactCanvas>
      <MyShape1 positionX= "10", positionY="10">
      <MyShape2>
      <MyGroupShape>
        <MyShape3>
      </MyGroupShape>
    <MyReactCanvas>
```

My goal is to have something like this :
[ETL Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkghk.png)

If you have some advice, article, code or informations how to use canvas with React

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is too broad. You can find many javascript/React based libraries to render tree diagrams by just googling it! Take [treant-js](https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/) for example.

Comment: I add more detail on the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are able to use the HTML5 `<canvas />` tags and behavior within your React project (if you're using React-Dom). If you have experience working with the HTML5 Canvas in pure HTML, it should be very similar to using it with React and you can place it within your JSX.

For example:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>HTML5 Canvas + React.js</h1>
      <canvas
        id="myCanvas"
        width="200"
        height="100"
        style={{ border: "1px solid #d3d3d3" }}
      >
        Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.
      </canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This example creates a `<canvas />` element and draws a line when the `<App />` component is rendered. See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yjvzcg) for a live example.

A recent article ["Canvas with React.js"](https://medium.com/@pdx.lucasm/canvas-with-react-js-32e133c05258) would be a good starting point.

Comment: thx Charles, is there a way to refresh just shapes inside canvas when we use setState with react and not all canvas ? 
in purpose to create a react component linked with a group of shapes inside canvas

Comment: Yes, you would do so by calling methods on `c` and `ctx` in the example above when the state changes.

Comment: if i understand, if i call ctx for example for add new shape on my canvas element the old shapes do not undergo any refresh ?

Comment: @idir, yes, if you call more methods on `ctx` (the context of the canvas element), then the old shapes will not undergo refresh. The canvas (and old shapes) will refresh when the entire component containing the `<canvas />` element is re-rendered. I have updated the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yjvzcg) to show adding a new shape.